# Combining substrings in Java

Tags: java, string, substring

I have this problem wherein the taken characters from the strings must combine in order to generate a unique pass code based on the user inputs. I'm currently stuck in coding, please help me: here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class GetInputFromUser{

   public static String a;
   public static Scanner in ;

   public static void main(String args[]) {

      String s;
      String y;
      String p;

      in = new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.println("LastName: ");
        s = in.nextLine();
        String trimmeds = s.substring(0, 3);
        System.out.println(trimmeds); 

         System.out.println("FirstName: ");
         y = in.nextLine();

        String trimmedy = y.substring(y.length() -3);
        System.out.println(trimmedy); 

        digit();
        if (!(a.length()==8)){
        System.out.println("error");
        digit();

      }

     }
        public static void digit(){
        System.out.println("8-digit ID Num.: ");
        a = in.nextLine();

        String trimmeda = a.substring(a.length() -3);
        System.out.println(trimmeda); 

   }

}
```

Here's the output of the program:

LastName: 
Dizon

Diz

FirstName: 
Kristen

ten

8-digit ID Num.: 
12345678

678

I need help in combining "Diz", "ten", and "678".

the last output should be "Dizten678".

Comment: Please don't be tag spamming. Delete irrelevant language tags.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: Maybe you should move the validation of `a` into the `digit` method, since `a` is out of scope, outside that method.  You could use some kind of loop in that method, to have the user repeat their input until they provide something acceptable.

Comment: Write a sample input and the output you want to obtain and tell where you are stucked!

Comment: I edited my question and added the output of the current program. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question but maybe, this code may work.
replace your function ***public static void digit()*** with this:

```
    public static void digit(){
            in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("8-digit ID Num.: ");
            a = in.nextLine();
            String trimmeda = a.substring(a.length() -3);
            System.out.println(trimmeda);
            System.out.println(s+y+trimmeda); // this line shows the output you want

       }
```

Comment: I edited my question and added the output of the current program. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

Combining a two substrings can be done like this;

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      String str = new String("Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com");
      String str1 = str.substring(10);
      // returns: Tutorialspoint.com
      String str2 = str.substring(10, 15);
      // returns: Tuto
      String finalStr = str1 + str2;
      // returns: Tutorialspoint.comTuto
   }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question and added the output of the current program. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: In that case `return trimmeda;` for `digit()` and set the return type to `String`, Then concatenate `String str = trimmedy + trimmeds + trimmeda;`. Assuming the rest of the code works.